# How to make sync call in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Hi i am trying to get user details in angular and based on user values i need to perform specific task, i am able to make the call to the api but response is taking some time and thats why i am unable to check the condition.

```
ngOnInit() {

this.getUserDetails();

  if((this.user.PrivacyNotice)) 
  {
       ------
  }
  else
  {
       ------
  }
 }

getUserDetails() {
this.user.Email = "test@test.com";

this.bookingListSubscription = this.restService.getUserProfile(this.user).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.user = data;
  });
}
```

Here user is the object of type UserVM Model which contains PrivacyNotice boolean field

following is the service method which makes the api call

```
getUserProfile(user: UserVM): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<UserVM>(this.getAPI('FetchUserProfile'),user,
  this.httpOptions).pipe(
    map(data => data),
    catchError(this.handleError<any>('getUserProfile'))
  );
```

}

in if i want to check the value of boolean flag PrivacyNotice which is returned from api so how can i achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the task in a `subscribe` callback.

```
this.bookingListSubscription = this.restService.getUserProfile(this.user).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.user = data;

    if((this.user.PrivacyNotice)) 
    {
         ------
    }
    else
    {
         ------
    }

  });
```

Comment: How can i do it in ngOnInit()

Comment: Ever heard about async/await & Promise ? All you need is a sync call to the api and perform the next operation @user9287106